# How can I group this query to return a single result?

Tags: mysql

I've got a database structure that I'm not able to change, but I'd like to find the most efficient way to get this data.

We have an game object that has 3 levels, and at the end of each level the game saves a single score to the database, with the levels score in the appropriate column, and 0s in the columns for the other levels.  Here it is illustrated:

DB Structure:

```
UserID | Score1| Score2| Score3| CreatedAt
1      |0      |0      |3      |<today>
1      |2      |0      |0      |<today>
1      |0      |5      |0      |<today>
1      |0      |0      |2      |<yesterday>
1      |0      |6      |0      |<yesterday>
1      |1      |0      |0      |<yesterday>
1      |0      |0      |6      |<3 days ago>
1      |0      |7      |0      |<3 days ago>
1      |4      |0      |0      |<3 days ago>
```

Now, yes it would be a better solution to have a structure like UserID | Score | LevelNumber | CreatedAT , but due to some other circumstances we're not able to change the structure.

So, what I'd like to be able to do is, make a query that will get the three latest scores, given a date.  For instance, in the example above, querying todays date would return a result with Score1: 2, Score2: 5, Score3: 3; and querying 2 days ago would give Score1: 4, Score2: 7, Score3: 6;

Comment: Are you allowed to fire the person prohibiting the change, and then make the change? Anyway, see UNION

Comment: Also, note that you have no PK. This is potentially highly problematic.

Comment: Sorry, the table does have a PK, just not listed.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Everyday, there are 3 scores. So '3 latest scores' is just the '3 scores accrued on the latest date at, or prior to, the target date', right?

Comment: I suppose I could have illustrated this more accurately by showing more than 3 scores per day -- the user can have any number of scores on a given day, and may not play some levels on days that they play other levels.  So, the need is, given a date and time, what are the most recent scores from that given time, for each level.  Basically, 'as of <date>, what was the users current score on each level?'

Comment: In that case, I agree. Considerable room for improvement ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```
select userid
     , s1
     , s2
     , s3
  from (
            select userid
                 , createdat
                 , sum(score1) s1
                 , sum(score2) s2
                 , sum(score3) s3
              from table
          group by userid
                 , createdat
       ) t
 where t.createdat = (
                        select max(t1.createdat)
                          from table t1
                         where t1.userid = t.userid
                           and t1.createdat <= <date_queried>
                      )
     ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your situation this query should be fine:

```
select max(Score1), max(Score2),max(Score3) FROM table where CreatedAt=<today>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,UserID INT NOT NULL
,Score1 INT NOT NULL
,Score2 INT NOT NULL
,Score3 INT NOT NULL
,CreatedAt DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table (userid,score1,score2,score3,createdat) VALUES
(1,0,0,3,'2015-02-04'),
(1,2,0,0,'2015-02-04'),
(1,0,5,0,'2015-02-04'),
(1,0,0,2,'2015-02-03'),
(1,0,6,0,'2015-02-03'),
(1,1,0,0,'2015-02-03'),
(1,0,0,6,'2015-02-01'),
(1,0,7,0,'2015-02-01'),
(1,4,0,0,'2015-02-01');

SELECT id,userid,score1 score,1 levelno,createdat FROM my_table
UNION ALL
SELECT id,userid,score2,2,createdat FROM my_table
UNION ALL
SELECT id,userid,score3,3,createdat FROM my_table
;
+----+--------+-------+---------+------------+
| id | userid | score | levelno | createdat  |
+----+--------+-------+---------+------------+
|  1 |      1 |     0 |       1 | 2015-02-04 |
|  2 |      1 |     2 |       1 | 2015-02-04 |
|  3 |      1 |     0 |       1 | 2015-02-04 |
|  4 |      1 |     0 |       1 | 2015-02-03 |
|  5 |      1 |     0 |       1 | 2015-02-03 |
|  6 |      1 |     1 |       1 | 2015-02-03 |
|  7 |      1 |     0 |       1 | 2015-02-01 |
|  8 |      1 |     0 |       1 | 2015-02-01 |
|  9 |      1 |     4 |       1 | 2015-02-01 |
|  1 |      1 |     0 |       2 | 2015-02-04 |
|  2 |      1 |     0 |       2 | 2015-02-04 |
|  3 |      1 |     5 |       2 | 2015-02-04 |
|  4 |      1 |     0 |       2 | 2015-02-03 |
|  5 |      1 |     6 |       2 | 2015-02-03 |
|  6 |      1 |     0 |       2 | 2015-02-03 |
|  7 |      1 |     0 |       2 | 2015-02-01 |
|  8 |      1 |     7 |       2 | 2015-02-01 |
|  9 |      1 |     0 |       2 | 2015-02-01 |
|  1 |      1 |     3 |       3 | 2015-02-04 |
|  2 |      1 |     0 |       3 | 2015-02-04 |
|  3 |      1 |     0 |       3 | 2015-02-04 |
|  4 |      1 |     2 |       3 | 2015-02-03 |
|  5 |      1 |     0 |       3 | 2015-02-03 |
|  6 |      1 |     0 |       3 | 2015-02-03 |
|  7 |      1 |     6 |       3 | 2015-02-01 |
|  8 |      1 |     0 |       3 | 2015-02-01 |
|  9 |      1 |     0 |       3 | 2015-02-01 |
+----+--------+-------+---------+------------+

SELECT a.*
  FROM 
     ( SELECT id,userid,score1 score,1 levelno,createdat FROM my_table
       UNION ALL
       SELECT id,userid,score2,2,createdat FROM my_table
       UNION ALL
       SELECT id,userid,score3,3,createdat FROM my_table
     ) a
 WHERE score > 0
   AND createdat <= '2015-02-02'
 ORDER 
    BY createdat DESC
     , levelno
 LIMIT 3;

+----+--------+-------+---------+------------+
| id | userid | score | levelno | createdat  |
+----+--------+-------+---------+------------+
|  9 |      1 |     4 |       1 | 2015-02-01 |
|  8 |      1 |     7 |       2 | 2015-02-01 |
|  7 |      1 |     6 |       3 | 2015-02-01 |
+----+--------+-------+---------+------------+
```